# Java Rest API method throws a 404 Not Found after publishing

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am hosting my Backend on Google App Engine and the Rest API works well on localhost. The method url is as follows:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/plans/getplans/242353
```

This works on local host and returns me a JSON response properly. It's a **GET** method and **242353** is the parameter I pass to the method.

But when I publish it to my Google Cloud, after I attempt to call it on my browser with the following URL:

```
http://2-dot-MY_APP_DOMAIN.appspot.com/rest/plans/getplans/242353
```

I get this error on my browser:

> **Error: Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /rest/plans/getplans/242353 was not found on this
>   server.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
     <param-value>com.dinukapj.socialapp.api</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Why does this happen? Do I need to add any other information to my web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hitting /resources/plans/getplans/242353 as defined in your web.xml

Comment: Without the /rest part?

Comment: ya instead of /rest/plans/getplans/242353 try /resources/plans/getplans/242353

Comment: Small problem, the rest api gets called but the database data is not delivered. This method basically gets a SELECT * query from the DB. Works in Localhost but not after I publish it. Is there any setting that I need to configure on Google Cloud before publishing? @Abilash